# Heroku rake aborted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, bundle

I am trying to run

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

but I keep getting this error

```
(in /app)
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:84: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
rake aborted!
test-unit is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:102:in `block in cripple_rubygems'
/app/lib/tasks/rspec.rake:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `block in load_with_new_constant_marking'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_with_new_constant_marking'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/rails.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/rails.rb:14:in `each'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/rails.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/app/Rakefile:11:in `require'
```

The app gets launched successfully

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
       Installing rails_log_stdout... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       All dependencies are satisfied
-----> Compiled slug size is 14.3MB
-----> Launching... done, v7
       http://young-robot-995.heroku.com deployed to Heroku
```

but I am getting this error

In my local development it looks like i am using ruby 1.8 but on heroku it looks like its 1.9.1 maybe thats causing it....any ideas on how to fix this

here is my gemfile if that will help

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

#gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'rails', '2.3.8'
gem 'will_paginate', '2.3.12'
gem 'googlecharts'
gem 'faker'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'bandsintown'
gem 'itunes-search-api','0.1.0', :path => 'vendor/gems/itunes-search-api-0.1.0'
gem 'i18n', '0.4.2'
gem "giggly", "~> 0.1.2"
gem "ruby-paypal",'0.0.5', :path => 'vendor/gems/ruby-paypal-0.0.5'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'
end
```

Comment: I know heroku requires the postgress gem so add `gem pg` to your gemfile or migrating will not work. Also it looks like you need the `test-unit` gem so install that too and see if you keep getting the same trace.

Comment: i am using sqllite not postgress though....do i still need it

Comment: Place it in a production gem group that way it only gets installed in production.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to modify your Gemfile, try using the one below and see if that works for you:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '2.3.8'
gem 'will_paginate', '2.3.12'
gem 'googlecharts'
gem 'faker'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'bandsintown'
gem 'itunes-search-api','0.1.0', :path => 'vendor/gems/itunes-search-api-0.1.0'
gem 'i18n', '0.4.2'
gem "giggly", "~> 0.1.2"
gem "ruby-paypal",'0.0.5', :path => 'vendor/gems/ruby-paypal-0.0.5'

group :production do
  gem 'test-unit'
  gem 'pg'
end


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'
end
```

Comment: seems logical but i am getting this error on bundle install Using googlecharts (1.6.7) 
Using itunes-search-api (0.1.0) from source at vendor/gems/itunes-search-api-0.1.0 
Installing pg (0.11.0) with native extensions /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:551:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

Comment: When you run bundle install run it as bundle install --without production. You need to do that every time you bundle locally to avoid having to install postgre SQL. I would suggest making an alias or something if you're on linux.

Comment: but i did get this rake aborted!
can't activate test-unit (= 1.2.3, runtime), already activated test-unit-2.3.1. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.

Comment: that means you already have test-unit installed before and you installed it again. uninstall the 1.2.3 version and you're good. also why is test-unit being loooked for in production? it should only be for development and testing

Comment: I was having the same problem, and adding the production block with "gem 'pg'" solved it! Thanks! +1!